# Determining Voltage Overshoot, Voltage Droop & Current Step

Tags: buck

I have a buck converter design in excel where i am trying to determine the output capacitor using the formulas in page19 of the [ADP1850](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP1850.pdf#page=19). It says select the largest result of the previous three equations. I am not sure how to determine the variables \$V_{Overshoot}\$, \$V_{Droop}\$, \$I_{Step}\$.

My specifications are as follows:

1. Frequency: 220kHz
2. \$V_{in}\$: 12V
3. \$V_{out}\$: 8.1V
4. Delta \$I_L\$: 10
5. \$I_{out}\$: 25A
6. Resr: 30m\$\Omega\$

Are they determined after prototyping ?

Comment: Why not do a sensitivity partial deivative or 10% tolerance change to see the result and figure out the C values that arrive at the same input values to see what is possible.

Comment: I’ve been following the datasheet and did not find anything relating to it. 

Not sure where to begin. How is the current step estimated ?

Comment: It depends on your load. A CPU might have a 50% step load something else 30% or 10%, others 100% which needs more care for overshoot prevention.

Comment: Thanks I meant how are the values substituted like as you mentioned are they in percentage of the actual value or in figures for example vovershoot would be 10% (0.1) of vout, 30% (0.3) of Iout.

Comment: What Tony is saying is it depends on your load.  As in the varyiance.  A CPU with a variable load, requires 50%, so \$t_{ON}\$ can vary to meet the needs of the load.  Designing a switcher requires a lot of understanding.

Comment: I understand that. I can see a voltage drop from 8V to 6V. So substituting it, is it in the form of an integer value or in percentage.